# need to parse up to 3rd / in a string by using regexp in sql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

when i am trying extract through `regexp` from the below source by using `\|(.*?),1,2` this, i am getting up to end but i need to 3rd / only. when i use  `\|(.*/){1,3},1,2` it is giving `http://localhost:6148372/content/bdsajf` and i am stuck up at ending search position. please help me on this.

```
U=https://www.abcdf.com/aecb/app/login|http://llcwokhfkdvc.webs.com/sajc-services
U=http://localhost:7438/en.html|http://localhost:6148372/content/bdsajf/en/kjf-LKJf/FJKSF-cbxjs.html
```

O/P should be # `http://llcwokhfkdvc.webs.com` and `http://localhost:6148372`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following expression:

```
\|([^/]*/*[^/]*)
```

See [live demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/rH1qM1)

Comment: your logic is working but i am in a confusion how this picks http as well, can you explain how it behaves ?

Comment: `[^/]*` matches everything up to the first `/` in `//` and then /* matches the two forward slashes, and `[^/]*` match everything up to the following `/`

Answer (score 0):

Try `'\|([^/]*/){1,3}'` (11i):

```
SQL> SELECT regexp_substr(txt, '\|(([^/]*/){1,3})', 1, 1, 'i', '1') regexp
  2    FROM DATA;

REGEXP
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://llcwokhfkdvc.webs.com/
http://localhost:6148372/
```

In 10g:

```
SQL> SELECT ltrim(regexp_substr(txt, '\|([^/]*/){1,3}'), '|') regexp
  2    FROM DATA;

REGEXP
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://llcwokhfkdvc.webs.com/
http://localhost:6148372/
```

Comment: I think the author didn't want the slash (/) sign at the end of the results.

Comment: Neither can I, but he wrote what he wants to get: `http://llcwokhfkdvc.webs.com` and `http://localhost:6148372` Just saying, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(t, '\|(http://.*?)/', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
  FROM (
    SELECT
      'U=https://www.abcdf.com/aecb/app/login|http://llcwokhfkdvc.webs.com/sajc-services' AS t
    FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT
      'U=http://localhost:7438/en.html|http://localhost:6148372/content/bdsajf/en/kjf-LKJf/FJKSF-cbxjs.htmlO/P should be # http://llcwokhfkdvc.webs.com and http://localhost:6148372' AS t
    FROM DUAL
);
```